# Run C program using command-line option

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing C program and running it using Linux VM. My program has one argument - directory name. Normally for arguments I use array (argv[]) and run my compiled program:`./programName directoryName`.
But my task requires run it like follow: `./programName -f directoryName` .
The second option doesn't work. How I should use it?

Comment: You want to handle the `-f`? What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Yes, I have to handle ```-f``` but I'm not sure what changes I have to do in my code in order to use it and pass ```directoryName``` argument.

Comment: The traditional way to parse command-line options on Unix systems is with `getopt`, and also `getopt_long` and `getopt_long_only`.  There are other libraries as well.

Comment: `argc` will be `3`; `argv[0]` will point to `"./programName"` (or something along these lines), `argv[1]` will point to `"-f"`; `argv[2]` will point to `"directoryName"`; `argv[3]` will be `NULL`